# iPhone address book - auto-select Phone owner

Tags: iphone, cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0

In 3.0 they have Auto-Fill for Safari. You go into the settings app to turn it on, and it needs to tie into an entry in the Address Book.

I went into the Settings app to set up mine, and I noticed that it already had guessed who I was. Was it doing this using something in the API? If so, how do I access this function?

My iPhone syncs up to Address Book on my Mac, and the desktop app knows who I am. Does the iPhone now look at this same property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no public API for identifying who the owner of the phone is.

If this is something you would like I recommend filing a bug report with the Apple developer connection.

Otherwise, (while I don't recommend it) you might be able to infer from the array returned from [[NSHost currentHost] names] who the device owner is.

Comment: There's no NSHost class in iPhone 3.0 SDK. There's NSFullUserName() [works in Simulator, haven't tested on the device].

Comment: NSFullUserName() just returns "Mobile User". Not sure that's going to be of much help. But you might be able to retrieve the phone number and key off of that. http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/01/iphone-dev-user-phone-numbers.ars