# Discovering the user's first and last names?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to programmatically discover the first and last names of the iPhone user. Is this possible at all? Calling this ...

```
getpwuid( getuid() )->pw_gecos == "Mobile User"
```

..alas. Iterating over the address book finds all address book records, but doesn't distinguish between the device owner and anyone else (that I can tell).

Given that the Mac desktop address book decorates the owners icon with a 'me' overlay in the bottom-left, I'm hoping that sort of information is available in the iPhone version.

Martin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the other thread, there is NSFullUserName() - this call does come up in the iPhone documentation so it should work on the device.  Simply parse out the first and last name from that.

Answer (score 2):

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022704/iphone-address-book-auto-select-phone-owner) - there is no public API for that.